# JSON Response find_all_playlists without video data

Tags: brightcove

When I saw that the api has a call find_all_playlists I was assuming it would do just that; find the playlists. Sadly this call also gets every bit of information of every video inside the playlists.

Is there a way to just request all playlists and get a response like this:

```
{ "items": [
    {
        "id": 1721334541001,
        "name" : "playlist 1"
    },
    {
        "id": 1721334541002,
        "name" : "playlist 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Hope someone has a solution for this.

Regards
- Drazen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the fields to be returned with the `playlist_fields` parameter.

```
http://api.brightcove.com/services/library?command=find_all_playlists&token=TOKEN&playlist_fields=id,name
```

Comment: Thank you I've been looking for this for a while and it kept adding video_fields to it.